# Laravel - alphabetical order

Tags: laravel

I would like to make an alphabetical sort in my function index().

[image]

I think I should use the `Order By` clause?

I am stuck in my code below:

```
public function index(Request $req)
    {
    if ($req->has('search') && !empty($req->search)) {

        $validated = $req->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', 
        ]);

        $auteurs = Auteur::where('nom', 'LIKE', '%' . $validated['search'] . '%')->paginate(5);
        $auteurs->appends($req->only('search'));
        return view('admin.auteurs.index', compact('auteurs'));
    }

    $auteurs = Auteur::paginate(5);
    return view('admin.auteurs.index', compact('auteurs'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use orderBy like this:

```
public function index(Request $req)
{
if ($req->has('search') && !empty($req->search)) {

    $validated = $req->validate([
        'search' => 'alpha', 
    ]);

    $auteurs = Auteur::where('nom', 'LIKE', '%' . $validated['search'] . '%')->orderBy('nom', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
    $auteurs->appends($req->only('search'));
    return view('admin.auteurs.index', compact('auteurs'));
}

$auteurs = Auteur::orderBy('nom', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
return view('admin.auteurs.index', compact('auteurs'));
}
```